# csv writer стирает данные в файле при записи

Tags: python, файлы, pandas, csv

Код записи данных:

```
with open("inbox.csv", mode="w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ",")
    w.writerow(["time", "id", "empl"])
```

Вывожу данные:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу добавить данные:

```
with open("inbox.csv", mode="w", encoding='utf-8') as file:
    w = csv.writer(file, delimiter = ",")
    w.writerow(["11", "22", "33"])
```

Вывожу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предыдущие данные стерлись. Мне нужно добавлять данные в файл в разные моменты времени, а не перезаписывать. Добавлял в код:

```
file.close()
```

Но это не помогло.

Подскажите, в чем проблема

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все потому что в строке

`with open("inbox.csv", mode="w", encoding='utf-8') as file:`

У вас **mode = 'w'**, а он сначала создает новый файл, а если файл с таким именем уже есть то усекает его, потом записывает в него данные, для того что бы записать данные в файл без изменения старых данных попробуйте указать **mode = "a"**, этот параметр запишет данные в файл без его усечения

`with open("inbox.csv", mode="a", encoding='utf-8') as file:`